# angular google maps show info window on mouse over

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I'm using [angular google maps](https://angular-maps.com/) and I'm trying to show the marker info window when the mouse is over the marker.

**view**

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let p of people" 
[iconUrl]="'/assets/user.png'" 
[latitude]="p.lat" [longitude]="p.lng"
(markerClick)="onMarkerClick(p)"  
(mouseOver)="showInfo(p)"  (mouseOut)="hideInfo(p)">
  <agm-info-window *ngIf="show">
    <div>Hello! {{p.nome}}</div>
  </agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
```

**component**

```
showInfo(p: Person){
    this.show = true;
    console.log(this.show);

  }

  hideInfo(p: Person){
    this.show = false;
    console.log(this.show);    
  }
```

I know that the event is correctly triggered because the logs are correct, but the info window never shows. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: By default, `agm-info-window`s need to be clicked on to open them, IIRC. You'll need to find a way to open it programatically if possible. All you're doing is causing them to exist for the given marker, but they are not displayed until clicked.

Comment: That is correct, thanks. In fact if I substitute the `agm-info-window` tag with a simple `div` tag it works. Plus, I have to move the div outside the `map` tag or it won't show. This behaviour doesn't make me happy but I'll think about a solution. Any other hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`agm-info-window` provides an option `[isOpen]` to show and hide the info-window. Bind the `show` property with [isOpen] to get the desired outcome.

```
<agm-info-window [isOpen]="show">
   <div>Hello! {{p.nome}}</div>
</agm-info-window>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<agm-info-window [isOpen]="show">
   <div>Hello! {{p.nome}}</div>
</agm-info-window>
```

In the agm-info-window [isOpen]="show", where show is an boolean you can use it with true or false from mouseOver function whichever.